# Does Liferay 6.0.5 serviceBuider work?

Tags: liferay

I am trying to develop a portlet that has a domain class and database mapping for it done with ServiceBuider. Classes and numerous config files get generated fine, but deploying fails to exception (don't have them available right now).

Is ServiceBuilder supposed to work in liferay sdk 6.0.5 for ordinary Liferay portlets, or is it usable only for ext-plugins/hook-plugins/ liferay Internals? Am I missing some other undocumented restrictions/dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup, ServiceBuilder is supposed to work from portlet plugins (and it definitely does). It's deprecated (but works) in ext plugin. See the [KnowledgeBase Portlet](http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/plugins/trunk/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet/) from the plugins (svn-username: "guest", password is empty)

To find a solution for your problems it would really help to get the exact steps you do as well as the exact exception.